How should I use the handleEnd event in the Multi-drag component of formkit/drag&drop?
in this link you can find the information of the librarie: https://drag-and-drop.formkit.com/
I am taking the example given in the library for the multi drag component and modifying it. I need to control the event when an element is dragged, the library provides a configuration for this, but I have not been able to call it correctly. I'm doing it this way and it doesn't work:
import React from 'react';
import { useDragAndDrop } from '@formkit/drag-and-drop/react';
import { multiDrag, selections } from '@formkit/drag-and-drop';

export function Test() {
  const mockFileNames = ["foo", "bar"];

  const customHandleEnd = (data) => {
    console.log('Drag ended', data);
  };

  const [parent1, files1] = useDragAndDrop<HTMLUListElement, object>(
    mockFileNames,
    {
      group: 'A',
      plugins: [
        multiDrag({
          plugins: [
            selections({
                selectedClass: 'bg-blue-500 text-white'
            })
          ],
          handleEnd: customHandleEnd
        })
      ]
    }
  );
  const [parent2, files2] = useDragAndDrop<HTMLUListElement, object>(
    [],
    {
      group: 'A',
      plugins: [
        multiDrag({
          plugins: [
            selections({
              selectedClass: 'bg-blue-500 text-white'
            })
          ],
          handleEnd: customHandleEnd
        })
      ]
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="p-px flex justify-between font-oldschool mt-20">
      <div
        ref={parent1}
        className="min-w-0 grow-0 border-2 md:border-4 border-indigo-300 w-full p-3 dark:bg-slate-800"
      >
        {
          files1.map((file) => (
            <span>{{file}}</span>
          ))
        }
      </div>
      <div
        ref={parent2}
        className="min-w-0 grow-0 border-2 md:border-4 border-indigo-300 ml-2 w-full p-3 dark:bg-slate-800"
      >
        {
          files2.map((file) => (
            <span>{{file}}</span>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I need to get the information of which element was dragged and to where.
